# How to add AWS managed policy through CloudFormation

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

I want to add AWS managed policy (AmazonSSMFullAccess) to a role using CloudFormation.
I tried to use  `AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy` but it creates a Customer Managed policy and I don't want that. I want it to be AWS managed.
Do you have any idea how can I do that?

I am trying to add AWS managed AmazonSSMFullAccess and here is the code I am using in mu CF template:

```
AmazonSSMFullAccess:
    Type: AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy
    Properties:
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - 'cloudwatch:PutMetricData'
              - 'ds:CreateComputer'
              - 'ds:DescribeDirectories'
              - 'ec2:DescribeInstanceStatus'
              - 'logs:*'
              - 'ssm:*'
              - 'ec2messages:*'
            Resource: '*'
          - Effect: Allow
            Action: 'iam:CreateServiceLinkedRole'
            Resource: >-
              arn:aws:iam::*:role/aws-service-role/ssm.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForAmazonSSM*
            Condition:
              StringLike:
                'iam:AWSServiceName': ssm.amazonaws.com
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - 'iam:DeleteServiceLinkedRole'
              - 'iam:GetServiceLinkedRoleDeletionStatus'
            Resource: >-
              arn:aws:iam::*:role/aws-service-role/ssm.amazonaws.com/AWSServiceRoleForAmazonSSM*
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
              - 'ssmmessages:CreateControlChannel'
              - 'ssmmessages:CreateDataChannel'
              - 'ssmmessages:OpenControlChannel'
              - 'ssmmessages:OpenDataChannel'
            Resource: '*'
```

[image: First line if the policy I get from CF and second one is the one I need]

Comment: Please provide the full template example and with exact description of what's happening and why it does not work.

Comment: @Marcin I have added the description in the question. So I am able to create customer managed policy but not aws managed policy through CF, that is my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You, as an AWS customer can only create customer managed policies. You **can't create AWS managed policies**, because only Amazon can do it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. I think I went the wrong way here. I don't want to create AWS managed policy, I just want to attach existing AWS managed policy to my role I have created. Is that also not possible?

Comment: @Alex Yes, its possible. You have to add them using [ManagedPolicyArns](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-role.html#cfn-iam-role-managepolicyarns).

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I need and it works perfectly. Thanks a lot!

Comment: There is a typo in link provided above, the proper link is – [ManagedPolicyArns](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-role.html#cfn-iam-role-managedpolicyarns)